# Vue favicon doesn't change in ios chrome & safari browser

Tags: vue.js, favicon, vue-cli

I alredy change the favicon.ico to the logo file which I want to use In Vue-cli's public folder, and named it the same file name.

In web browser the Favicon and title be changed successful
[image]

but in the mobile browser neither safari or chrome are fail
[image]

[image]

I didn't use pwa so probably not have manifest.json problem

And I already tried to clean both browser's cache or open it on Incognito Windows, but still the same, is anything I neglect to do with my index.html or vue-cli config?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png">` so that your favicon is shown when you favorite the page or view it in that tabs view. This is mentioned [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

For the webpage itself its very likely your iPhone is still caching the old icon regardless of your attempts to clear said cache. In my experience trying to load the page with no network connection, waiting for the time out error and then connecting to the network and reloading the page is the best way to "force" the device to clear its cache. Alternatively with the dev tools open and a keyboard attached type `command + option + r`. If not, patience, it'll update... eventually.